# Question about linear algebra in Benson's book: intersections of images or sum of kernels

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra

I am not sure if this question is suitable in here. I asked [this question in *Mathematics*](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3427839/453628) some days ago.

The following proposition is in Benson's book “*Representation theory of elementary abelian groups and vector bundles*”:

> Proposition 4.1.2 Suppose $k$ is algebraically closed. Let $A_1,A_2\in M_{n\times m}(k)$, regarded as maps from $k^m$ to $k^n$. Then:
>   (1) Suppose that forall $\lambda,\mu\in k$, not both zero, $\lambda A_1+\mu A_2$ is injective. Then $$\bigcap_{(\lambda,\mu)\neq (0,0)}Im(\lambda A_1+\mu A_2)=0$$
>   (2) Suppose that forall $\lambda,\mu\in k$, not both zero, $\lambda A_1+\mu A_2$ is surjective. Then $$\sum_{(\lambda,\mu)\neq (0,0)}Ker(\lambda A_1+\mu A_2)=k^m$$

This is very interesting proposition and the proof in the book is very beautiful. The proof in the book used field extension. I am wondering if this can be proved by methods of linear algebra. Any helps will be appreciated.

The following is proof in the book:
[image]

Th4.1.1 is that the rank is preserved when consider field extension and take algebraic independent variables.

Comment: Shouldn't you say $m\neq n$? Otherwise, both seem false.

Comment: @Mohan Thank you. We need $k$ is algebraically closed. Suppose $k$ is algebraically closed,  if $\lambda A_1+\mu A_2:V \rightarrow V$ is isomorphism for all $\lambda,\mu$ not both zero, where $V$ is finite dimensional $k$ vector space, then $V=0$.

Comment: @Mohan No, $m=n$ is a trivial case, as the assumption is then impossible. Indeed, the assumption for $m=n$ is that $P:(\lambda,\mu)\mapsto\det(\lambda A_1+\mu A_2)$ satisfies $P^{-1}(\{0\})=\{(0,0)\}$. Since the field is algebraically closed, this is impossible (the zero set of any nonconstant polynomial in $\ge 2$ variables is infinite).

Comment: @YCor Thank you for your comment and your edit of this question. I  added the condition of algebraically closed in the question after I saw Mohan's comment. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a proof which only uses linear algebra, but I have one in the context projective geometry.

I will prove the second statement you mention. Let $m \geq n$ and let $M$ be the generic matrix of size $m \times n$ with linear coefficients. Let $V = \mathbb{k}^m$, $W = \mathbb{k}^n$ and $X = \mathbb{P}(\mathrm{Hom(V,W)})$. The matrix $M$ induces a map:
$$ V \otimes \mathcal{O}_X(-1) \longrightarrow W \otimes \mathcal{O}_X.$$

Assume there exists $A_1,A_2 \in X$ such that for all $(\lambda,\mu) \in \mathbb{k}^2 -\{0,0\}$, the matrix $\lambda A_1 + \mu A_2$ is surjective. This is equivalent to saying that the restriction of $M$ to the $\mathbb{P}^1$ joining $A_1$ to $A_2$ in $X$ is surjective. We thus have an exact sequence:

$$0 \longrightarrow F \longrightarrow V\otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1_{A_1,A_2}}(-1) \longrightarrow W \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1_{A_1,A_2}} \longrightarrow 0,$$

where $F$ is the kernel of $M$ restricted to this $\mathbb{P}^1_{A_1,A_2}$.

Assume by absurd that $\sum_{A \in \mathbb{P}^1_{A_1,A_2}} Ker A \neq \mathbb{k}^m.$ Dualizing, this is equivalent to $\bigcap_{A \in \mathbb{P}^1_{A_1,A_2}} (Ker{A})^{\perp} \neq 0$, where $(Ker A)^{\perp} \subset V^{*}$ is the orthogonal to $Ker A$ in $V^*$.

From the above exact sequence, we see $F^{\perp} \simeq W^* \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1_{A_1,A_2}}(-1)$. Now the hypothesis $\bigcap_{A \in \mathbb{P}^1_{A_1,A_2}} (Ker{A})^{\perp} \neq 0$ exactly translates as $F^{\perp}$ has a non-zero constant section over $\mathbb{P}^1_{A_1,A_2}$, namely the map:
$$ x  \longrightarrow (x,p),$$
where $p$ is a non-zero vector in $\bigcap_{A \in \mathbb{P}^1_{A_1,A_2}} (Ker{A})^{\perp}$.

This is impossible as $H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1))=0$.

Comment: This is really nice. Thank you. I can't understand in the final of the proof.  Why this translates it has a non-zero constant section? What is the map of $x\rightarrow (x,p)$  and why this contradicts with the last equation? Thank you.

Comment: @sky : The map $x \longrightarrow (x,p)$ goes from $\mathbb{P}^1_{A_1,A_1}$ to the (total space) of the vector bundle $F^{\perp}$. The bundle $F^{\perp}$ is a sub-bundle of the trivial bundle $V^* \otimes \mathcal{O}_X$ and there, the intersection $\bigcap_{A \in \mathbb{P}^1_{A_1,A_2}} F^{\perp}_{A}$ is non-zero. If $p$ is a non-zero vector in this intersection, then we can define a non-zero constant section of $F^{\perp} \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{1}_{A_1,A_2}$ as specified.

Comment: Finally, the notation $H^0(X, E) $ is the usual notation for the vector space of algebraic sections of an algebraic vector bundle $E \longrightarrow X$ over an algebraic variety. The computation $H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1)) = 0$ is rather standard and basically says that there are no rational fractions of degree $-1$ globally defined on $\mathbb{P}^{1}$.